# StreamGraph for React Native w/ D3JS. Need to consolidate all the areas into a single area. Iteration is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, d3.js

We're trying to create this stream graph in React Native :
https://observablehq.com/@d3/streamgraph

This is the data that I want to create series from below:

```
const data = [
  {
    time: 1, travel: 1000, politics: 734, sports: 782, business: 655, technology: 745, fashion: 353, society: 430, shopping: 228, science: 239, spirituality: 274, realestate: 236, pets: 125, news: 154, homeandgarden: 19, hobbies: 89, healthfitness: 236, food: 154, finance: 19, familyparenting: 125, education:  236, career: 274, cars: 239, entertainment: 353
  },
  {
    time: 2, travel: 1023, politics: 694, sports: 779, business: 587, technology: 812, fashion: 349, society: 409, shopping: 240, science: 262, spirituality: 232, realestate: 223, pets: 112, news: 173, homeandgarden: 25, hobbies: 45, healthfitness: 223, food: 173, finance: 25, familyparenting: 112, education:  223, career: 232, cars: 262, entertainment: 349
  },
  {
    time: 3, travel: 983, politics: 739, sports: 789, business: 623, technology: 669, fashion: 381, society: 311, shopping: 226, science: 213, spirituality: 247, realestate: 192, pets: 140, news: 152, homeandgarden: 17, hobbies: 56, healthfitness: 192, food: 152, finance: 17, familyparenting: 140, education:  192, career: 247, cars: 213, entertainment: 381
  },
.
.
.
.
];
```

This is the actual creation of the series (slices) below

```
const stack = d3.shape.stack()
.keys([
  "travel",
  "politics",
  "sports",
  "business",
.
.
.
.

])
.offset(d3.shape.stackOffsetWiggle)
.order(d3.shape.stackOrderNone)

const series = stack(data)


const scaleX = d3.scale.scaleLinear()
      .range([0, height])


const scaleY = d3.scale.scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.array.min(series, d => d3.array.min(d, d => d[0])), d3.array.max(series, d => d3.array.max(d, d => d[1]))])
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])

const area1 = d3.shape.area()
  .x((d, i) => scaleX(i))
  .y0(d => scaleY(d[0]))
  .y1(d => scaleY(d[1]))
  .curve(d3.shape.curveCardinal)(series[0]);

const area2 = d3.shape.area()
.x((d, i) => scaleX(i))
.y0(d => scaleY(d[0]))
.y1(d => scaleY(d[1]))
.curve(d3.shape.curveCardinal)(series[1]);

const area3 = d3.shape.area()
.x((d, i) => scaleX(i))
.y0(d => scaleY(d[0]))
.y1(d => scaleY(d[1]))
.curve(d3.shape.curveCardinal)(series[2]);

const area4 = d3.shape.area()
  .x((d, i) => scaleX(i))
  .y0(d => scaleY(d[0]))
  .y1(d => scaleY(d[1]))
  .curve(d3.shape.curveCardinal)(series[3]);

.
.
.
.
```

and so on , we made 12 areas to represent 12 slices for the 12 hours in a day

we used this color fn to color the slices

```
  const color = d3.scale.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(series)
    .range(d3.chromatic.schemeAccent)
```

And then we're using 12 path components to render the area

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.root}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Svg{...{width, height}}>
          <Path d = {area1} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area2} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area3} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area4} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area5} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area6} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area7} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area8} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area9} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area10} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area11} fill={z(Math.random())}/>
          <Path d = {area12} fill={z(Math.random())}/>

        </Svg>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>

  )
  }
}
```

It ends up looking like this :

[image]

How do we create a single component that will render the same image ? we tried many different iterations methods but couldn't get them to work. We've spent almost a week on this. And a more viable solution would be appreciated . =)

Comment: What is the reason, that you want to recreate this chart in react native? I advise you to keep d3.js code contained by itself and don't build your chart out of multiple react components or templates. Instead use plain es6 or typescript classes to split your code. It will keep your call stacks short and the developers sain. Introducing a frontend framework into this, will unnecessarily complicate development, testing, debugging and communication between different parts of the chart. I am speaking from experience.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your prompt reply. How do we do that ? Where do we put the D3 js code and how do we call it into react native ?

Comment: Put the complete chart into a single react component. Create the bare minimum <svg> container with react and let d3.js do the rest. You could use a custom hook to get d3js introduced.